# Custom Message on Work.com Goals Page

Tags: visualforce, work.com, goals

I want to add custom message using Visualforce on work.com goals page.I looked into [documentation of work.com](https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/workcom_implementation_guide.pdf) but I don't see anything here. How to do this?

[image]

I see goal pagelayout under set up but not sure where it is uses...I was looking to customize above page but no luck

[image]